# Show a properties file message when using @Pattern?

Tags: java, regex, spring-annotations

I'm using @Pattern to validate a field:

```
@Pattern(regexp = Patterns.ZIP_CODE, message="validation.ZIP_CODE")
private String zip;
```

In my messages.properties file I have this:

```
validation.ZIP_CODE=Must match NNNNN or NNNNN-NNNN
```

The javadocs seem to imply that it should look up the validation.ZIP_CODE message:

```
Returns:
The error message template.
Default:
"{javax.validation.constraints.Pattern.message}"
```

But instead I get the text:

```
validation.ZIP_CODE
```

Am I misunderstanding the javadoc, or am I implementing this incorrectly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to use an internationalized message in a JEE 6 Pattern annotation, I believe you must wrap the property name in open/close curly braces.

```
@Pattern(regexp = Patterns.ZIP_CODE, message="{validation.ZIP_CODE}")
private String zip;
```

Comment: No success here - I have tried "{validation.ZIP_CODE}" and "{messages.validation.ZIP_CODE}" and what I get back is the same value wrapped in the curly braces.

Comment: Ha.  Quite by accident I stumbled on the answer (well, AN answer anyway.)  The JEE6 documentation here:   http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gkahi.html    indicates that "The Validationmessages resource bundle and the locale variants of this resource bundle contain strings that override the default validation messages. "    So if you want your messages to appear, you have to have {curly.braces} around them and they have to go in the ValidationMessages.properties file (or files.)

Comment: I don't understand this explanation. Please provide a sample. or better still correct my error. Thank you. my properties file has the following zone.error = Zone code must be two alphabet characters in length. my @Pattern message="{zone.error}"

Comment: What about if i want to read regexp from a properties file. How can I achieve this?